# Fetch last 10 hours of data from Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to fetch last 10 hours of data from redshift using a query dynamically. But sql format doesn't seem to work. 
Do we need some specific redshift commands or I am missing something ?

Comment: provide more details about your data model, dynamic may have different meaning in different context, so please elaborate more.

Comment: For future reference, please supply more information in your StackOverflow questions so that people can understand what you are asking. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

was able to resolve the issue with :  GETDATE() - INTERVAL '10 HOURS' in the WHERE clause